# Can I rollback Firebase app(For Android) which I deleted unfortunately

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-console

I have deleted firebase app from console(For Android). My App is live now how can I rollback deleted app. or Any option.

Comment: Hi. By "*I have deleted firebase app from console(For Android)*", do you mean from the list of apps only?

Comment: Yes only app deleted. Project Still have.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You deleted the **database** (from Firebase console) or your app (from your mobile device)?

Comment: Not database. Setting->Project Settings-> General-> Where I have Android App list that is I created. But unfortunately It deleted by me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to rollback/revert once the app is deleted from the list. It is deleted permanently from the list along with the Anayltics Data associated with it. As can bee seen in the warning:

[image]

But you can just add it back again, the same way you add a new app, through  <kbd>ADD APP</kbd>  (*button also seen in the screenshot*).